How to get process mitigation policies in kernel mode?
I need to write code for a driver. I need to get information about all the mitigation policies of a process.  This is how I get the process handle :
`HANDLE h_process{};
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES obj_attr{};
CLIENT_ID client_id{.UniqueProcess = ULongToHandle(process_id), .UniqueThread = nullptr};

InitializeObjectAttributes(&obj_attr, nullptr, OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, nullptr, nullptr)

NTSTATUS status = ZwOpenProcess(&h_process, PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, &obj_attr, &client_id);`

As I understand it, it is possible to get policy information using this function:
`NTSTATUS WINAPI ZwQueryInformationProcess(
  _In_      HANDLE           ProcessHandle,
  _In_      PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  _Out_     PVOID            ProcessInformation,
  _In_      ULONG            ProcessInformationLength,
  _Out_opt_ PULONG           ReturnLength
);`

But I don't understand what structure I should give to **ProcessInformation **field.
Could you please help me.
The only thing I've found on the subject is this article:
https://ntdoc.m417z.com/process_mitigation_policy_information
They suggest to use the union of the structures of all policies:
`typedef struct _PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY_INFORMATION
{
    PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY Policy;
    union
    {
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_ASLR_POLICY ASLRPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_STRICT_HANDLE_CHECK_POLICY StrictHandleCheckPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_SYSTEM_CALL_DISABLE_POLICY SystemCallDisablePolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_EXTENSION_POINT_DISABLE_POLICY ExtensionPointDisablePolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_DYNAMIC_CODE_POLICY DynamicCodePolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_CONTROL_FLOW_GUARD_POLICY ControlFlowGuardPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_BINARY_SIGNATURE_POLICY SignaturePolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_FONT_DISABLE_POLICY FontDisablePolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_IMAGE_LOAD_POLICY ImageLoadPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_SYSTEM_CALL_FILTER_POLICY SystemCallFilterPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_PAYLOAD_RESTRICTION_POLICY PayloadRestrictionPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_CHILD_PROCESS_POLICY ChildProcessPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_SIDE_CHANNEL_ISOLATION_POLICY SideChannelIsolationPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_USER_SHADOW_STACK_POLICY UserShadowStackPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_REDIRECTION_TRUST_POLICY RedirectionTrustPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_USER_POINTER_AUTH_POLICY UserPointerAuthPolicy;
        PROCESS_MITIGATION_SEHOP_POLICY SEHOPPolicy;
    };
} PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY_INFORMATION, *PPROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY_INFORMATION;`

But if I pass it to ProcessInformation, I get the status 0xC00000BB (The request is not supported.).
I also tryed to pass a single policy structure (**PROCESS_MITIGATION_DEP_POLICY ** for example), but then I get status 0xC0000004(The specified information record length does not match the length that is required for the specified information class.).
If I try to get the requested structure size, I always get 0x0
`NTSTATUS status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(h_process,
                   ProcessMitigationPolicy,
                   &policy_struct,                                       
                   sizeof(PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY_INFORMATION),
                                             &ret);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
       logger::printLog<logger::LogLevel::Warning>("Failed to 
       check PROCESS_MITIGATION_DEP_POLICY. Status: 0x%X, 
       ret:0x%X\n", status, ret);
       return;
}`


What is the actual code that you are using? From my reading of the documentation it seems like it should be called like so:
PROCESS_MITIGATION_POLICY_INFORMATION data; data.Policy = PROCESS_MITIGATION_DEP_POLICY;  NTSTATUS status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessMitigationPolicy, &data, sizeof(data), &ret);
